# Verisign SSL certificate keystore apache tomcat (java.io.IOException: invalid URI name)

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, verisign

I have 7 file of .cer generated from Verisign
It's contain

2 CA Certificate Root file
2 VeriSign Primary and Secondary intermediate file
2 VeriSign EV SSL
1 myApp certificate

then I try using keytool to add certificate to my keystore file by

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias aliasName -keystore keystoreFile.jks -file certificate.cer
```

So, When I use this command with root certificate I met this message error and system ask me to trust this certificate ?

```
#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
Unparseable CRLDistributionPoints extension due to
java.io.IOException: invalid URI name:file://\\fhqrathsmca01\CertEnroll\XXXXXXXXXXXX CA.crl

0000: 30 74 30 72 A0 70 A0 6E   86 35 68 74 74 70 3A 2F  0t0r.p.n.5http:/
0010: 2F 66 68 71 72 61 74 68   73 6D 63 61 30 31 2F 43  /fhqrathsmca01/C
0020: 65 72 74 45 6E 72 6F 6C   6C 2F 4B 41 53 49 4B 4F  ertEnroll/XXXXXX
0030: 52 4E 42 41 00 4B 25 32   30 43 41 2E 63 72 6C 86  XXXXXX%20CA.crl.
0040: 35 66 69 6C 65 3A 2F 2F   5C 5C 66 68 71 72 61 74  5file://\\fhqrat
0050: 68 73 6D 63 61 30 31 5C   43 65 72 74 45 6E 72 6F  hsmca01\CertEnro
0060: 6C 6C 5C 4B 41 53 49 4B   00 55 55 55 01 55 44 20  ll\XXXXXXXXXXXX
0070: 43 41 2E 63 72 6C                                  CA.crl
```

java.io.IOException: invalid URI name:file://

I don't know .cer invalid or not ?

can any one please suggest me step by step,If I miss something
or if this problem has an answer to solve

Comment: Can you check exactly which of these certificate files has this extension? You should be able to do this with `openssl x509 -text -in filename.crt` (possibly with `-inform DER` too).

Comment: @Bruno I try to contact with cert admin and I have an answer that I should use only VeriSign Primary and Secondary intermediate file to be root cetificate and myApp certificate.
But I got new problem like 
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match` 

I think it's happen because of cryptographic padding or algorithm between X.509 and PKCS7 

I have to find the answer